# early return on devise active_for_authentication method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have two user types, `Parent` and `Child`.
I have an active_for_authentication method on `Child` which uses a is_suspended column on `Child` which works perfectly.

However a Parent can 'masquerade' into a childs account, and i want the active_for_authentication method to return true in this case (even if the child is suspened).

So ideally the method on `Child` would look like this:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  return true if masquerading?
  super && !is_suspended?
end
```

However after a lot of googling it seems as though no devise methods are accessible here.
So i'm now stuck on the next approach.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I edited your question. The snippets feature is for examples of HTML/JS/CSS that are runnable in the browser. For all other code use 4 spaces of indentation or fenced markdown blocks (```). There is also a button on the editor (`{}`) that will indent by 4 spaces.

Comment: You also need to provide us with some more context. Where is the `masquerading?` method defined? `as though no devise methods are accessible here` is also kind of nonsensical as models are a different context and you most likely are attempting to call a controller method or helper method inside a model which doesn't work at all in Rails since models are not aware of the request or controller by design.